# Reflection Read PE Heaps

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, stream, metadata

Is it possible to read data from a specific heap in a .net PE by using the System.Reflection Namespace?

Heaps are also known as streams and are in the Metadata of a .net assembly:

[image: Example of heap meta data]

For more detailed Information please check out the msdn page: [MSDN - PE Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8dkk3ek4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Is it possible to read the data (bytes) one of these tables contains by using Reflection?

Comment: There are libraries coming with Roslyn now that does this, else use Mono.Cecil.

Comment: Yes, I know that Mono.Cecil.dll and dnlib.dll can do that, but is it also possible with reflection? (Like with on-board-tools of a .net PE? ;P )

Comment: Nope, nothing builtin. There might be some native library to do this, but IMO, it will be a PITA ;p

Comment: Even the native metadata interfaces make a point of not exposing the raw metadata.  It was designed to be compact, not to be easy to read.